# open() syscall sometimes fails and sometimes succeeds

Tags: c

I'm trying to understand why this is sometimes works, and sometimes doesn't -
the open and read syscalls.

```
//open files   
fd1=open(argv[1],"O_RDONLY");
if(fd1==-1){
   printf("open file number 1 failed\n");
   exit(0);
} 
fd2=open(argv[2],"O_RDONLY");
if(fd2==-1){
    printf("open file number 2 failed\n");
    exit(0);
}

//read first byte
r1=read(fd1, &byte1, 1);
if(r1==-1){
    printf("read 1 1 error\n");
    close(fd1);
    exit(0);
}
r2=read(fd2, &byte2, 1);
if(r2==-1){
    printf("read 2 error\n");
    close(fd2);
    close(fd1);
    exit(0);
}
```

The output:

```
~/Desktop/os$ ./comp/out 1.txt 2.txt
open file number 1 failed
~/Desktop/os$ ./comp/out 1.txt 2.txt
read 1 1 error
~/Desktop/os$ ./comp/out 1.txt 2.txt
open file number 1 failed
~/Desktop/os$ ./comp/out 1.txt 2.txt
open file number 1 failed
~/Desktop/os$ ./comp/out 1.txt 2.txt
read 1 1 error
~/Desktop/os$ ./comp/out 1.txt 2.txt
read 1 1 error
```

Or as image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkvNC.png

Comment: Tangential advice: It will be much easier to troubleshoot problems like this in the future if you make a habit of _always_ printing, in your error messages, the name(s) of all file(s) involved in the failing system call, and the decoded value of `errno`.  For example, `printf("open file number 1 failed\n");` should have been `fprintf(stderr, "open(%s) failed: %s\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));`

Comment: The OP should definitely add [perror()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) (or equivalent) to his error handling, and compile with "-Wall" (or equivalent) to mitigate problems like "illegal argument" type (literal string "O_RDONLY" vs oflag constant O_RDONLY).

Comment: The compiler should be shrieking at you for the erroneous calls to `open()`.  If it wasn't shrieking, it's beyond time to turn up the warning level, or get a better compiler.

Answer (score 5):

```
"O_RDONLY"
```

Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

You want

```
O_RDONLY
```

What's going on here is the second argument is a (mostly bitflags) number, and you're passing a string. Due to ASLR, the second argument is randomized so it works sometimes but not other times.

Comment: turning on warnings will help [just fine](https://godbolt.org/z/6Tvrr7e8a).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I see compilers have improved.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. It's the optional _third_ argument to `open` that warnings won't help with. [for instance](https://godbolt.org/z/rcr3njaWh)

Comment: @zwol: I'm used to `open()` being declared as `int open()` for which it would not help. As I said, compilers have improved.

Comment: @Joshua Ah, I see you (like me) cut your Unix teeth in the previous century.

Comment: @Joshua - the OP would REALLY benefit if you emphasized the importance of [perror()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) or equivalent...  Along with enabling warnings (e.g. "-Wall")

Comment: `int open()`... Have you not used C since the early 90's?

Comment: @Shawn. I have. I haven't passed a bad argument to open since the early 2000s (while possessing a 90s compiler).

Comment: Normally I bust out in all directions advocating use of strerror/perror, but in this (thankfully rare) case, it probably wouldn't have helped!  "Invalid argument" wouldn't necessarily have clued the OP in to the extra quotes.  (Why the OP's compiler didn't complain about the wrong type is another question entirely.)

Comment: @SteveSummit: I'm projecting "file exists" as often as not, which would have been actively misleading.